# Unable to use non ascii chars (accents) in Windows Credentials Provider

Tags: c++, windows, credentials, credential-providers, credential-manager

I'm creating a Windows Credentials Provider using the Microsoft's "Sample All UI" example.

As French speaker, i need to use accents like that : "éàèê". All my strings are widechar strings (syntax: L"Numéro de téléphone"), and all the strings functions i use are the widechar version (wcsdup, wcscpy...)

But when i load my provider, accents spawn as a set of random chars like © or Ã.
It clearly looks like an encoding error, but I cant find how.

Are Credentials providers supporting special chars ?
I known that default credential provider in french will display accents.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Not a help but may be a hint: As German speaker, I see often `Ã` as first of two characters for `äöüß` when something is written (encoded) in UTF-8, but displayed (decoded) with these ancient Windows-ANSI-1252 character stuff.

Comment: Windows is UTF-16 through and through. Looking at `ICredentialProviderUser::GetStringValue` and the like, I see just `LPWSTR`.

Comment: I know that it is LPWSTR, that why i cannot understand why i get this issue.

Comment: Maybe the issue is non inside of code but inside of compiled DLL? Try to compile your resources using 1200 code page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally loaded my text as UTF-8 from a file, and conveted it to UTF-16 with this function :

```
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0);
```

Note the flag : CP_UTF8

I used theses generated strings, and it worked.